# SQL number of rows valid in a time range grouped by time

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, grouping, intervals

SQL Server

I have a table with 2 time stamps, time_start and time_end.
e.g.

```
ID    time_start           time_end
----  -------------------  -------------------
1     2019-01-01 08:30:00  2019-01-01 09:40:00
2     2019-01-01 09:10:24  2019-01-01 15:14:19
3     2019-01-01 09:21:15  2019-01-01 09:21:19
4     2019-01-01 10:39:45  2019-01-01 10:58:12
5     2019-01-01 11:39:45  2019-01-01 11:40:10
```

and I would like to group them so I can have the number of rows grouped by a variable time interval. 
e.g.

```
time_interval         row_count
-------------------   ---------
2019-01-01 07:00:00   0
2019-01-01 08:00:00   1
2019-01-01 09:00:00   3
2019-01-01 10:00:00   2
2019-01-01 11:00:00   1
2019-01-01 12:00:00   0
```

My interval could be 1 hour, 1 minute, 30 minutes, 1 day, etc...

Think of it as a log-in/log-out situation, and I want to see how may users were logged at any given minute, hour, day, etc...

Comment: Outer join a recursive cte (or table) returning the needed time_interval values. GROUP BY. Done!

Comment: sounds like a "count overlapping intervals" problem.

Comment: Or a tally of the times and then group them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
     DECLARE @start_date datetime='2019-01-01',
                @end_date datetime='2019-01-02',
                @i_minutes int=60

        DECLARE @t TABLE
        (
            id int identity(1,1),time_start datetime,time_end datetime
        )
        INSERT INTO @t(time_start,time_end)VALUES
        ('2019-01-01 08:30:00','2019-01-01 09:40:00'),
        ('2019-01-01 09:10:24','2019-01-01 15:14:19'),
        ('2019-01-01 09:21:15','2019-01-01 09:21:19'),
        ('2019-01-01 10:39:45','2019-01-01 10:58:12'),
        ('2019-01-01 11:39:45','2019-01-01 11:40:10')

        --SELECT @start_date=min(time_start),@end_date=max(time_end)
        --FROM @t

        ;WITH CTE_time_Interval AS
        (
            SELECT @start_date AS time_int,@i_minutes AS i_minutes
            UNION ALL
            SELECT dateadd(minute,@i_minutes,time_int),i_minutes+ @i_minutes
            FROM CTE_time_Interval
            WHERE time_int<=@end_date
        )
        ,CTE1 AS
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY time_int)AS r_no,time_int 
            FROM CTE_time_Interval
        )
        ,CTE2 AS
        (
            SELECT a.time_int AS Int_start_time,b.time_int AS Int_end_time 
            FROM CTE1 a
            INNER JOIN CTE1 b ON a.r_no+1=b.r_no
        )

SELECT a.Int_start_time,a.Int_end_time,sum(iif(b.time_start is not null,1,0)) AS cnt
FROM CTE2 a
LEFT JOIN @t b ON
(
    b.time_start BETWEEN a.Int_start_time AND a.Int_end_time 
    OR 
    b.time_end BETWEEN a.Int_start_time AND a.Int_end_time
    OR
    a.Int_start_time BETWEEN b.time_start AND b.time_end
    OR
    a.Int_end_time BETWEEN b.time_start AND b.time_end 
)
GROUP BY a.Int_start_time,a.Int_end_time
```

Comment: In your solution you don't have the count of users logged for a long interval. For example there is a user that log in at 09:10:24 and log out at 15:14:19, so you have to count that user a 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00 and 15:00

Comment: @VíctorBeltrán, i have made some changes, now it works

Comment: I ended up using this version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is my workaround.
I created a table "test" with your data.

First I get the min and max intervals and after, I get all the intervals between these values with a CTE. 
Finally, with this CTE and a left join with the intervals between time_start and time_end I got the answer.

This is for intervals of 1 hour

```
DECLARE @minDate AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @maxDate AS DATETIME;

SET @minDate = (select case 
when (select min(time_start) from test) < (select min(time_end) from test) 
then (select min(time_start) from test)
else (select min(time_end) from test) end )
SET @minDate = FORMAT(@minDate, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:00:00')

SET @maxDate = (select case 
when (select max(time_start) from test) > (select max(time_end) from test) 
then (select max(time_start) from test)
else (select max(time_end) from test) end )
SET @maxDate = FORMAT(@maxDate, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:00:00')

;WITH Dates_CTE
     AS (SELECT @minDate AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(hh, 1, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @maxDate)

SELECT d.Dates as time_interval, count(*) as row_count
FROM   Dates_CTE d
LEFT JOIN test t on d.Dates 
between (FORMAT(t.time_start, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:00:00')) 
and (FORMAT(t.time_end, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:00:00'))  
GROUP BY d.Dates
```

For intervals of 10 minutes you need some changes.
First I format dates getting minutes `(dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm:00 instead of dd-MM.yyyy HH:00:00)` 
and in the left join I approach time_start and time_end to their 10 minutes time (9:32:00 in 9:30:00) `(dateadd(minute, 10 * (datediff(minute, 0, time_start) / 10), 0))`:

```
DECLARE @minDate AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @maxDate AS DATETIME;

SET @minDate = (select case 
when (select min(time_start) from test) < (select min(time_end) from test) 
then (select min(time_start) from test)
else (select min(time_end) from test) end )
SET @minDate = FORMAT(@minDate, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm:00')

SET @maxDate = (select case 
when (select max(time_start) from test) > (select max(time_end) from test) 
then (select max(time_start) from test)
else (select max(time_end) from test) end )
SET @maxDate = FORMAT(@maxDate, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm:00')

;WITH Dates_CTE
     AS (SELECT @minDate AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(minute, 10, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @maxDate)

SELECT d.Dates as time_interval, count(*) as row_count
FROM   Dates_CTE d
LEFT JOIN test t on d.Dates 
between dateadd(minute, 10 * (datediff(minute, 0, time_start) / 10), 0) 
and dateadd(minute, 10 * (datediff(minute, 0, time_end) / 10), 0)
GROUP BY d.Dates
```

And finally I get this results for 1 hour intervals:

```
+---------------------+-----------+
|    time_interval    | row_count |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 01/01/2019 08:00:00 |         1 |
| 01/01/2019 09:00:00 |         3 |
| 01/01/2019 10:00:00 |         2 |
| 01/01/2019 11:00:00 |         2 |
| 01/01/2019 12:00:00 |         1 |
| 01/01/2019 13:00:00 |         1 |
| 01/01/2019 14:00:00 |         1 |
| 01/01/2019 15:00:00 |         1 |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the time intervals.  The rest is a `LEFT JOIN`/`GROUP BY` or correlated subquery:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(datetime, '2019-01-01 07:00:00') as dt
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, dt)
      from dates
      where dt < '2019-01-01 12:00:00'
     )
select dates.dt, count(t.id)
from dates left join
     t
     on dates.dt < t.time_end and
        dates.dt >= dateadd(hour, 1, t.time_start)
group by dates.dt
order by dates.dt;
```

If you have lots of data and lots of time periods, you might find that this has poor performance.  If this is the case, ask a *new* question, with more information about sizing and performance.